# SQL INNER JOIN con tres tablas

Tags: java, sql

Tengo una base de datos sobre películas y quiero mostrar el nombre de los géneros que tiene asignado una película.

Diagrama (valores de ejemplo en color rojo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**-- EDITADO--**

Sale este error:

> The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String

Código:

```
public DefaultTableModel tableRegistros() {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;

        sSQL = "SELECT PELICULAS.*, " 
                + "GENEROS.nombre AS nombreGenero, " 
                + "COMPANIAS.nombre AS nombreCompania " 
                + "FROM PELICULAS " 
                + "INNER JOIN COMPANIAS ON PELICULAS.id_compania = COMPANIAS.id_compania " 
                + "INNER JOIN PELICULAS_GENEROS ON PELICULAS.id_pelicula = PELICULAS_GENEROS.id_pelicula " 
                + "INNER JOIN GENEROS ON PELICULAS_GENEROS.id_genero = GENEROS.id_genero";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

            String [] titulosColumnas = {"ID", "Título", "Año", "Minutos", "Sinopsis", "Compañía", "Género"};
            ArrayList<Object[]> registros = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                registros.add(new Object[] {
                    rs.getInt("id_pelicula"),
                    rs.getString("titulo"),
                    rs.getInt("anoLanzamiento"),
                    rs.getInt("longitudMinutos"),
                    rs.getString("sinopsis"),
                    rs.getString("nombreCompania")
                    rs.getString("nombreGenero") // Error: The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String
                });
            }

            model = new DefaultTableModel(registros.toArray(new Object[0][]), titulosColumnas);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: tableRegistros()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return model;
    }
```

La idea es:

- Obtener el nombre de la compañía en lugar del id_compania.
- Obtener todos los nombres de los géneros que tenga asignado una
  película.

Qué tengo mal en el query?. Soy novato con INNER JOIN.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te falta la palabra `ON` y creo que por eso te confundiste. Prueba así: `SELECT PELICULAS.*, "
                + "generos.nombre AS nombreGenero "
                + "FROM PELICULAS "
                + "INNER JOIN peliculas_generos ON PELICULAS.id_pelicula = peliculas_generos.id_pelicula "
                + "INNER JOIN generos ON peliculas_generos.id_genero = generos.id_genero"`. Si tus nombres de tabla son todos en mayúsculas, ponlos igual en tu consulta, eso podría darte problemas según el SO donde se ejecute el programa. Quité la columna compañías, no aparece JOIN de esa tabla.

Comment: ¿Y su tabla `compania`?

Comment: @A.Cedano He editado la foto de mi post inicial para que se pueda ver la tabla `COMPANIAS` también. He usado tu código, pero, me marca error de syntax. o.o

Comment: @Dev.Joel Cierto, he editado la foto de mi post inicial, ahora podrás ver la tabla `COMPANIAS` también. Espero puedas ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
"SELECT PELICULAS.*, " 
    + "GENEROS.nombre AS nombreGenero, " 
    + "COMPANIAS.nombre AS nombreCompania " 
    + "FROM PELICULAS " 
    + "INNER JOIN COMPANIAS ON PELICULAS.id_compania = COMPANIAS.id_compania " 
    + "INNER JOIN PELICULAS_GENEROS ON PELICULAS.id_pelicula = PELICULAS_GENEROS.id_pelicula " 
    + "INNER JOIN GENEROS ON PELICULAS_GENEROS.id_genero = GENEROS.id_genero"
```

**Notas:**

1. He puesto los nombres de tablas en mayúsculas, asumiendo que son así, por las imágenes.
2. Cuando te toque buscar el `titulo` de la película, puede que tengas problemas, no sé si te has dado cuenta de que llamaste `titutlo`  a esa columna.

Comment: Gracias, pero, aún no funciona, me sigue saliendo el error `The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String` en la línea `rs.getString("nombreGenero")`, alguna idea?. He actualizado mi post inicial con el código y la línea que lanza el error, a lo mejor el problema es otro ahora. Realmente no se qué pueda ser.

Comment: Ooootra dichosa coma falta aquí: `rs.getString("nombreCompania"),`   y vas a tener problema con el titulo: `rs.getString("titulo"),`  **lee mi nota 2,** según la imagen esa columna se llama **titu.....t....lo**  @RobertGomez

Comment: -.- genial, es algo tan vergonzoso, jeje. Ya ví el error en el nombre de la tabla, ya lo he arreglado en SQL, gracias por esa observación, ni me había fijado. :)

Comment: ¿Quien no se ha *comido una coma* al menos una vez en su vida @RobertGomez?

Comment: Todavía no entiendo cómo hiciste para unir el Género y la Película. Sé que fué con el último `INNER JOIN`, pero, no le entendí, en esa línea no hay `id_pelicula` por  ningún lado. Cómo SQL sabe a cuál película pertenece entonces?. o.o

Comment: @RobertGomez tú tienes una tabla intermedia llamada `PELICULAS_GENEROS` que es la que sirve para saber a qué géneros pertenece cada película. Dado que una película puede tener varios géneros en tu diseño se usa esa tabla intermedia para expresar una relación *muchos a muchos*, lo cual es correcto. De lo contrario, tendrías filas duplicadas en tus otras tablas. Ese JOIN se hace aquí: `INNER JOIN PELICULAS_GENEROS ON PELICULAS.id_pelicula = PELICULAS_GENEROS.id_pelicula` La tabla `PELICULAS_GENEROS` como su nombre lo indica, sirve de intermediaria entre `PELICULAS` y `GENEROS`.

Comment: vale vale, entonces, SQL hace los `INNER JOIN` que estén primero, y si después hago mas `INNER JOIN`, tomará encuenta el resultado de los `INNER JOIN` anteriores, al menos así lo entendí. Ya lo tengo mas claro, gracias